Goose embedded migration error: `dir not found`
I am working on a CLI tool so i want that when a user first runs the tool then i migrate all the tables into their database. I am using postgresql here.
I am getting into this error:
2024/10/30 17:05:01 error applying migrations: error applying migrations: sql/schema/ directory does not exist
exit status 1

When the sql/schema/ directory is present in my project directory.
This is my migrate.go file:
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "embed"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/pressly/goose/v3"
)

// Embed the migrations
// go:embed sql/schema/*.sql
var migrations embed.FS

func applyMigrations(db *sql.DB) error {
    // Set the base file system for Goose to embedded FS
    goose.SetBaseFS(migrations)

    if err := goose.SetDialect("postgres"); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error setting dialect: %w", err)
    }

    // Run migrations
    if err := goose.Up(db, "sql/schema/"); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error applying migrations: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}


This is main.go file:
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
        ...
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", cfg.DBURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error connecting to db: %v", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Apply migrations
    if err := applyMigrations(db); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error applying migrations: %v", err)
    }

        ...

This is my project structure
.
├── internal
│   ├── config
│   └── database
├── main.go
├── sql
│   ├── queries
│   └── schema
└── sqlc.yaml

sql/schema holds the SQL tables. I am excepting that i will run the migration, instead it is showing this error.
What might be the problem here?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
